# Question on extending densely defined linear operators on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space.

> Is there a theorem that states that for a densely defined continuous
>   linear operator $T: D(T) \subset H \to H$ there exists a unique
>   continuous linear extension to $H$?

And furthermore,

> If $T$ is an isometry then so is its extension?

I tried to find something about this and I found [here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densely_defined_operator) that this is true for an abstract Wiener space. But I don't know about Wiener spaces and I think there should be a more basic proof because Hilbert spaces are already *nice* spaces.

> If the answer is affirmative to either of my question could please
>   either provide a reference to a book or similar where I can study the
>   proof or else post a proof in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [continuous linear extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension), which is slightly more general than you need it to be.

Comment: Thanks and what about the isometric case? And the article you link to does not appear to contain a proof. I'd appreciate a proof or reference to a proof.

Comment: For example: *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications* - Kreyszig; p. 99 (Theorem 2.7-11).

Comment: See a link to the book [here](http://www-personal.acfr.usyd.edu.au/spns/cdm/resources/Kreyszig%20-%20Introductory%20Functional%20Analysis%20with%20Applications.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, I have the book. Also, the isometric case follows from this case.